# NumPy Data Type Not Understood

Tags: python, numpy

I have a script where I am attempting to parse a JSON and send to an Esri file geodatabase using NumPy.   I am receving an error for my latitude and longitude fields which should be floats stating that the data type is not understood.

```
import jsonpickle
import arcpy
import json
import numpy
import requests



X = 471316.3835861763
Y=  5000448.782036674


fc = "C:\MYLATesting.gdb\MYLA311"
if arcpy.Exists(fc):
  arcpy.Delete_management(fc)

f = open('C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\myla311.json', 'r')

data = jsonpickle.encode( jsonpickle.decode(f.read()) )

url = "myUrl.com"
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/plain', 'Accept': '/'}

r = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)


decoded = json.loads(r.text)

# print json.dumps(decoded, sort_keys=True, indent=4)


#
# vehicles = []
# for Response, ServiceRequest in decoded.iteritems():
#         vehicles.append(tuple(item[k] for k in ndtype.names))
#          print response, ServiceRequest




ndtype = numpy.dtype([
   ('status', 'S12'),
   (X, numpy.float64),
   (Y,  numpy.float64)


])


vehicles = []
for item in decoded['status']:
   vehicles.append(tuple(decoded(X(Y[k] for k in ndtype.names))))

narr = numpy.array([vehicles],  ndtype)
arcpy.da.NumPyArrayToFeatureClass(narr, fc,[X, Y] , sr)
```

Decoded JSON:

```
{
    "Response": {
        "ListOfServiceRequest": {
            "ServiceRequest": [
                {
                    "ActionTaken": "", 
                    "AddressVerified": "Y", 
                    "Anonymous": "N", 
                    "AssignTo": "North Central - 104 - IED", 
                    "Assignee": "Siebel Administrator", 
                    "CreatedByUserLogin": "PRASAD89", 
                    "CreatedDate": "12/31/2014 13:49:23", 
                    "CustomerAccessNumber": "", 
                    "Email": "prasadpotale@gmail.com", 
                    "FirstName": "Prasad", 
                    "HomePhone": "3123123123", 
                    "IntegrationId": "1420033765921", 
                    "LADWPAccountNo": "", 
                    "Language": "English", 
                    "LastName": "Pp", 
                    "Latitude": "34.064937", 
                    "ListOfAuditTrailItem2": {}, 
                    "ListOfChildServiceRequest": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BarricadeRemoval": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BeesOrBeehive": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BillingCsscAdjustment": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BillingEccAdjustment": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BillingRsscAdjustment": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BillingRsscExemption": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BrushItemsPickup": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311BusPadLanding": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311Containers": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311CurbRepair": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311DocumentLog": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311Flooding": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311GeneralStreetInspection": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311GenericBc": {
                        "La311GenericBc": [
                            {
                                "ATTRIB_08": "", 
                                "ListOfLa311GenericbcAuditTrail": {}, 
                                "NAME": "41572025-3803-49c4-8561-6e7ef41775df", 
                                "PAR_ROW_ID": "1-N607", 
                                "ROW_ID": "1-N60A", 
                                "TYPE": "GIS"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "ATTRIB_08": "", 
                                "ListOfLa311GenericbcAuditTrail": {}, 
                                "NAME": "a5b5b2b9-d2e7-400a-bf75-1138ff013caa", 
                                "PAR_ROW_ID": "1-N607", 
                                "ROW_ID": "1-N609", 
                                "TYPE": "Homeless Encampment"
                            }, 
                            {
                                "ATTRIB_08": "", 
                                "ListOfLa311GenericbcAuditTrail": {}, 
                                "NAME": "010420150405", 
                                "PAR_ROW_ID": "1-N607", 
                                "ROW_ID": "1-RN2D", 
                                "TYPE": "Subscription"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "ListOfLa311GisLayer": {
                        "La311GisLayer": [
                            {
                                "A_Call_No": "", 
                                "Area": "", 
                                "BOSRadioHolderName": "", 
                                "CommunityPlanningArea": "Westlake", 
                                "Day": "", 
                                "DirectionSuffix": "", 
                                "DistrictAbbr": "", 
                                "DistrictName": "Central", 
                                "DistrictNumber": "104", 
                                "DistrictOffice": "North Central", 
                                "Fraction": "", 
                                "LastUpdatedBy": "", 
                                "Name": "41572025-3803-49c4-8561-6e7ef41775df", 
                                "R_Call_No": "", 
                                "SectionId": "5279800", 
                                "ShortDay": "", 
                                "StreetFrom": "BOYLSTON ST", 
                                "StreetLightId": "", 
                                "StreetLightStatus": "", 
                                "StreetTo": "FIRMIN ST", 
                                "Type": "GIS", 
                                "Y_Call_No": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "ListOfLa311GraffitiRemoval": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311GuardWarningRailMaintenance": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311GutterRepair": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311HomelessEncampment": {
                        "La311HomelessEncampment": [
                            {
                                "ApprovedBy": "", 
                                "AssignedTo": "", 
                                "CompletedBy": "", 
                                "Contact": "", 
                                "ContactDate": "", 
                                "Crew": "", 
                                "DateCompleted": "12/31/2014 00:00:00", 
                                "InspectedBy": "", 
                                "InspectionDate": "", 
                                "LastUpdatedBy": "", 
                                "Location": "Alley", 
                                "Name": "a5b5b2b9-d2e7-400a-bf75-1138ff013caa", 
                                "OptionalTrackingCode": "", 
                                "Type": "Homeless Encampment"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalAutoRepair": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalConstruction": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalConstructionFence": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalDischargeOfWater": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalDumpingInProgress": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalDumpingPickup": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalExcavation": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalSignRemoval": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311IllegalVending": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311InformationOnly": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311LandMudSlide": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311LeafBlowerViolation": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311ManualPickup": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311MedianIslandMaintenance": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311MoveInMoveOut": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311MultipleStreetlightIssue": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311NewsRackViolation": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311Obstructions": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311Other": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311OvergrownVegetationPlants": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311PalmFrondsDown": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311Pothole": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311Resurfacing": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SanitationBillingBif": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SanitationBillingCssc": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SanitationBillingEcc": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SanitationBillingInquiry": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SanitationBillingLifeline": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SanitationBillingRssc": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SanitationBillingSrf": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311ServiceNotComplete": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311ServiceRequestNotes": {
                        "La311ServiceRequestNotes": [
                            {
                                "Comment": "", 
                                "CommentType": "External", 
                                "CreatedByUser": "PRASAD89", 
                                "CreatedDate": "12/31/2014 13:49:23", 
                                "Date1": "", 
                                "Date2": "", 
                                "Date3": "", 
                                "FeedbackSRType": "", 
                                "IntegrationId": "1420033765921", 
                                "IsSrNoAvailable": "N", 
                                "ListOfLa311SrNotesAuditTrail": {}, 
                                "Notification": "N", 
                                "Text1": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "ListOfLa311SidewalkRepair": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SingleStreetlightIssue": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SrPhotoId": {
                        "La311SrPhotoId": []
                    }, 
                    "ListOfLa311StreetSweeping": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311StreetTreeInspection": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311StreetTreeViolations": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311SubscribeDuplicateSr": {
                        "La311SubscribeDuplicateSr": [
                            {
                                "Activeflag": "Y", 
                                "EmailId": "pratik.desai@yoopmail.com", 
                                "LastUpdatedBy": "", 
                                "Name": "010420150405", 
                                "Type": "Subscription"
                            }
                        ]
                    }, 
                    "ListOfLa311TablesAndChairsObstructing": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311TreeEmergency": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311TreeObstruction": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311TreePermits": {}, 
                    "ListOfLa311WeedAbatementForPrivateParcels": {}, 
                    "LoginUser": "", 
                    "Longitude": "-118.252968", 
                    "MobilOS": "iOS", 
                    "NewContactEmail": "", 
                    "NewContactFirstName": "", 
                    "NewContactLastName": "", 
                    "NewContactPhone": "", 
                    "Owner": "BSS", 
                    "ParentSRLinkDate": "", 
                    "ParentSRLinkUser": "", 
                    "ParentSRNumber": "", 
                    "ParentSRStatus": "", 
                    "ParentSRType": "", 
                    "Priority": "Normal", 
                    "ReasonCode": "", 
                    "RescheduleCounter": "", 
                    "ResolutionCode": "", 
                    "SRAddress": "1200 W TEMPLE ST, 90026", 
                    "SRAddressName": "", 
                    "SRAreaPlanningCommission": "Central APC", 
                    "SRAreaPlanningCommissionId": "4", 
                    "SRCity": "", 
                    "SRCommunityPoliceStation": "", 
                    "SRCommunityPoliceStationAPREC": "RAMPART", 
                    "SRCommunityPoliceStationPREC": "2", 
                    "SRCouncilDistrictMember": "Gilbert Cedillo", 
                    "SRCouncilDistrictNo": "1", 
                    "SRCrossStreet": "", 
                    "SRDirection": "W", 
                    "SRHouseNumber": "", 
                    "SRNeighborhoodCouncilId": "44", 
                    "SRNeighborhoodCouncilName": "GREATER ECHO PARK ELYSIAN NC", 
                    "SRNumber": "1-1080871", 
                    "SRStreetName": "TEMPLE", 
                    "SRSuffix": "ST", 
                    "SRTBColumn": "E", 
                    "SRTBMapGridPage": "634", 
                    "SRTBRow": "2", 
                    "SRType": "Homeless Encampment", 
                    "SRUnitNumber": "", 
                    "SRXCoordinate": "6485064", 
                    "SRYCoordinate": "1846114", 
                    "ServiceDate": "12/31/2014 00:00:00", 
                    "Source": "311", 
                    "Status": "Open", 
                    "UpdatedByUserLogin": "PRASAD89", 
                    "UpdatedDate": "12/31/2014 13:49:23", 
                    "Zipcode": "90026"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        "NumOutputObjects": "1"
    }, 
    "status": {
        "cause": "", 
        "code": 311, 
        "message": "Service Request Successfully Queried."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to name your fields `'X'` and `'Y'`:

```
ndtype = numpy.dtype([
('status', 'S12'),
('X', numpy.float64),
('Y',  numpy.float64)
])
```

At the moment you are refering to actual `float` objects `X` and `Y` here, which isn't the right syntax for declaring a `dtype`. The above statement declares it using a `list` of `tuple`s where each `tuple` is a string name followed by a data type (or string that can be resolved into a data type).

Comment: Yes, I did not catch that, however that posts another problem, If I would like to include my defined X and Y fields how would that be handled in the ndtype?  These are in fact my X and Y fields.

Comment: It might help to give an example of your `decoded` JSON here - it's this it seems you need to parse into values in your array with `dtype` `ndtype` we've just defined.

Comment: My keys are apparently status and response while my values are those above in the decoded JSON, yet I cannot use a simple key/value function to return i.e. response, latitude

Comment: So... which of the fields in your decoded JSON dictionary do you want to end up in `'status'`, `'X'`, and `'Y'` in your NumPy structured array?

Comment: Yes, while giving a latitude and longitude to the X and Y fields.

Comment: You don't need to give us the WHOLE JSON!